# In Outlook, trying to set default reminder time for appointments in custom Calendar folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

I've created a custom form in Outlook 2007 and made it the default form for posting to custom Calendar folder.  My end goal is to set the default reminder time. To that end, I've set the "Reminder" property to "No" and "Reminder Beforehand" to 0 and published the form.

[image: Form Designer]

When I try to create a new appointment using this form, the interface simply defaults back to the system-level default reminder time of 15 minutes.

[image: NoReminder2 Appointment Form]

If I reopen the custom form in Form Designer, the properties are reset back to "Yes" and "15".
Any ideas?

I'm not looking for a solution such as Reminder Manager.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or two? This functionality is not widely-used, so hard to picture.

Comment: Absolutely.  I added a few that should help clarify.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to try re-creating this later. I will post back, evne if I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It appears to be caused by the "default reminder" Calendar option (in Tools|Options).

I did not want to disable that option, as I want normal appointments to have normal reminders. Thus, I opened the Design Form window, chose `View Code` and entered:

```
Function Item_Open()
  ReminderSet = False
End Function
```

This sets the reminder to 'None' *every time* the appointment is opened for editing. Not perfect, because it means that if you *do* want a reminder and set it, this'll be removed the next time you open it for editing. But it's good enough for my purposes.

Unfortunately, I could not find some `On_Create` type of event to make this work smoother.

ps. Do you know a way to make custom forms more accessible? (i.e. by a shortcut or by adding it to the New.. dropdown)

Comment: Useful answer. I found that "Function Item_Write()..." also works.